# Howto create code from wsdl and separated Xsd

Tags: c#, .net, xsd, wsdl

i got a local wsdl file referencing two separate Xsd files. 
how can I create the relate [c#] classes to that service ?

I tried to use wsdl.exe , but it ignores the Xsd files located in the same folder

Comment: `wsdl` creates Classes *from* WebServices. If you want to create classes from XSD files look into the Microsoft [`xsd tool`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: Wsdl.exe is rather old. Can't you use svcutil.exe? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe

Comment: "referencing two separate Xsd files" make sure the local paths work, post that part if you can't resolve it.

Comment: @rene thanks enough. running svcutil.exe without parameters listed: " svcutil *.wsdl *.xsd /language:C#" - all i need

Answer (score 1):

solved by a hint of @rene

running " svcutil *.wsdl *.xsd /language:C#" from Developer Command Prompt